# Basic idea of Firebase + GTM, is Google Analytics completely necessary?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I'm somewhat confused about the flow of data in this integration, do I need a GA account to make use of GTM's functionality, or can I just keep the tags inside GTM/send them back to firebase?

I'm an iOS developer and need to tag my already existing firebase events in GTM, but not sure if I'm understanding the big picture here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send data to Google Analytics. In fact, Firebase tags in GTM don't have any field where you can insert the Property ID of Google Analytics. Using them you send the events to the Firebase project that you have configured in its console.

Comment: So basically when I'm using GTM's Firebase Analytics tags, I'm asking for it to send them back to my firebase project, right? If thats true, I haven't been able to specify which firebase console to do so, am I missing something here?
Thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: In Prerequisites look at this part 'In the Firebase console, add your app to your Firebase project': https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5#add-gtm-to-project

Comment: I mean, I already have a fully functioning Firebase Analytics setup, but what I'm having troubles with is having GTM listen to my firebase events, Does GTM just runs off any firebase projects existing on my account? I'm running them on different accounts so not sure that's an issue.

Comment: In reality, GTM can do nothing, events are sent directly to Firebase Analytics. With GTM you can possibly block them, add them or modify them.